# How can I go back and forth through two windows in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am using PyQt5 to create two windows, main window and info window. I want to go back and forth through them, such that

1. initial state:
   if main window is opened
   I can click button info
2. If button info is clicked
   info window is opened, main is closed
   I can click main button

3.
If main button is clicked
info window is opened, main is closed

However, If I'd run the program from main window,
I'll be able to go to info, but not come back to main, through main button

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "~/Description.py", line 259, in Show_Main
    Info.close()
NameError: name 'Info' is not defined
```

similarly, If I'd run the program from info window, I'd be able to go to main, but not back to info

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "~/M.py", line 259, in Show_Main
    Form.close()
NameError: name 'Info' is not defined
```

This is partial code from each .py file:

M.py

```
from Description import Ui_Form

class Main_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Main")
     .
     .
     .
    def Show_Description(self):
        self.DWindow = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi2(self.DWindow)
        self.DWindow.show()
        Form.close()
```

descrpition.py

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi2(self, Info):
        Info.setObjectName("info")

    def Show_Main(self):
        from M import Main_Form
        self.DWindow = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.ui = Main_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.DWindow)
        self.DWindow.show()
        Info.close()
```

Don't ask me why am I importing Main_Form inside the Show_Main method rather than out of it, it would return an error otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message is saying that it can not recognize variable `Info`. From the code you've uploaded, variable `Info` is given to the class `Ui_Form` through the function `setupUi2`. But fucntion `Show_main`, the one that is creating error, does not share the variable `Info` that is given to the `setupUi2`, because it's not an instance variable. I guess you can try something like this :

```
def setupUi2(self,Info):
    self.Info = Info
    self.Info.setObjectName("info")

def Show_Main(self):
    ~~~
    self.Info.close()
```

Comment: I have done same concept to Show_Description as well, now it works just fine. Thanks.